# MobileFirst Platform adapter won't let me send a JSON array in body

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm using MobileFirst Platform 6.3, I'm trying to send the following request:

```
var input = {
    method : 'post',
    path : "/create/item.aspx",
    body: {
        contentType:'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        content: JSON.stringify([{"item": "name"}])
    }
};

var outputObj = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

I have minimized the request as much as I can just to simplify the issue, basically having a string that contains an array in body.content causes some unknown behavior and the body doesn't get sent to the backend.

I can't modify the backend so wrapping the array or sending a different input structure is not an option.

Can someone please explain what's happening to my body content and how can I stop WorkLight from modifying it?

Comment: What are you expecting to receive on your backend? Because this indeed sends that json string as the body of the request. That request looks something like this:
  
POST /create/item.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: {yourhost}
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8
Cache-Control: no-cache

[{"item":"name"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set up a simple nodejs server just to see what data do I receive from adapter and everything works just fine.

My adapter code:

```
    var input = {
    method : 'post',
    returnedContentType : 'plain',
    path : "/mypath",
    body:{
        contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        content: JSON.stringify([{"item": "name"}])
    }
};


return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

results in server output:

```
Thu Dec 11 2014 11:18:47 GMT-0600 (CST)     URL :: /
Thu Dec 11 2014 11:18:47 GMT-0600 (CST)     Method :: POST
Thu Dec 11 2014 11:18:47 GMT-0600 (CST)     Header :: content-length=17
Thu Dec 11 2014 11:18:47 GMT-0600 (CST)     Header :: content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Thu Dec 11 2014 11:18:47 GMT-0600 (CST)     Header :: host=localhost:1111
Thu Dec 11 2014 11:18:47 GMT-0600 (CST)     Header :: connection=Keep-Alive
Thu Dec 11 2014 11:18:47 GMT-0600 (CST)     Header :: user-agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)
Thu Dec 11 2014 11:18:47 GMT-0600 (CST)     Cookies >> undefined
Thu Dec 11 2014 11:18:47 GMT-0600 (CST)     Body :: [{"item":"name"}]
```

The problem might be on your backend side... What do you receive from a backend in response? Add returnedContentType : 'plain' property to your invocation options and check what is returned from WL.Server.invokeHttp()

Comment: You were right, I went by bad hint given by my colleague and obsessed about it without checking my backend.